# Executing stored procedure using .dbml file LINQ

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, linq, stored-procedures

Using VS 2013 (VB) and SQL Server 2012.

I execute a stored procedure to populate a gridview using linq.

```
Dim db As New GMConnectionDataContext
Dim gasHedges = db.GasHedges_create2ndMonth.ToList
```

The stored procedure returns a result set and has been working fine as in it returns the expected result and the gridview displays as desired.

I added some data to my SQL table and loaded the web page and the new data does not show.  IF I execute the stored procedure in SQL Server the new data shows. If I execute the stored procedure in VS the new data shows.

Now the weird bit. If I delete the reference to the stored procedure from the `.dbml` file then re-add it the new data shows when the page is loaded. I know that when using this file if I add columns to a table then I need to delete it and re-add the table to the `.dbml` file.

Surely the same isn't the case with stored procedures as they would be unusable. Is there something I am missing?

UPDATED

I think I know why this happening but I don't know how to fix it.  The SQL result set has dynamic columns as I use the pivot command in SQL. This means that if a user creates a new Gas company the result set will have another column and the datacontext must interpret that as the SP having changed and still shows the old dataset.  This does mean I cannot just delete the SP from the datacontext and re-add it as the web application needs to handle if the user adds another company.

Answer (score 0):

Any changes you make in SQL server are not auto-synched to your .dbml file. If you make table or stored procedure changes you need to delete them from the .dbml file and add them again.

Comment: SO I need to do this everytime I run the stored procedure?

Comment: Also how do I do this

Comment: Yes. Any changes you make will need to be updated in your .dbml file. If you expand your dbml you'll see a designer file, and in that is definitions for your stored procedures and tables. These need to be regenerated when changes are made. In Visual Studio, open the .dbml file and you'll see your tables and stored procs. You can just right-click and delete whatever changed. Then, open your server explorer and expand the connection that your dbml is using and drag and drop the updated items. Build your project and everything will be updated.

Comment: Updated my original question as I think I know why this is happening just not how to fix it.

Comment: If you have dynamic columns, you'll have to use an SQLCommand and a DataReader to call the stored procedure instead of your DataContext.

Comment: @MikeHE I don't think you need to use a SQLCommand and DataReader.  You should be able to use the DataContext, but you will need to specify a different return type than the one defined in your dbml file.

Comment: @RobertMcKee I thought about that as well, but I don't think that would be the easiest way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Best practices would dictate that you don't pivot your data in SQL.  Pivotting data is not a data related issue; it's presentation and should be done in the presentation layer -- in the application.